# How to provide flowtype hints in React.CreateClass for object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have some React code that uses components created with React.createClass.

Some of the components store things on the object as normal properties, e.g. `this.foo` as opposed to `this.props.foo` or `this.state.foo`.

Is there any way to provide a hint to Flow about the 'foo' property? I'd like to avoid rewriting these components for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide an explicit type to the object passed to `createClass`. Something like

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

type Spec = { foo: string };

const spec: Spec = {
  foo: 'bar',
  render() {
    return <div>{this.foo}</div>;
  }
}

const MyComponent = React.createClass(spec);
```

or if you prefer keeping the types inline, just use a cast

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = React.createClass(({
  foo: 'bar',
  render() {
    return <div>{this.foo}</div>;
  }
}: { foo: string }));
```

To prove this works, try setting `foo` to `42`. Flow will complain

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = React.createClass(({
  foo: 42, // <-- error: number. This type is incompatible with string
  render() {
    return <div>{this.foo}</div>;
  }
}: { foo: string }));
```